# how to get data from multiple inputs using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, blob

I have multiple inputs, I need with one button to upload all files from all the inputs (image and/or video), I found a code on web, but I can't find a way to upload or get all my files.

I am new to this procedure and unable to figure out the problem (maybe the `.get()` function is not right).

How to get all the files from all the inputs in one button click?..

**HTML:**

```
<div id="back" class="back">                        
    <label id="addPicture" onclick="locatePicture(this)" 
           style="color:white;font-size:larger" 
           for="theInput">Add Image</label>
    <div style="float: left">
        <input id="theInput" type='file'  />
    </div>          
    <div style="float: right">             
        <label id="addVideo" for="uploadFileVideo" style="color:white;font-size:larger" class="AjaxList_Button">Add Video</label>
        <input id="uploadFileVideo"  type='file'  />                             
    </div>                                           
</div>

<input type='Button' ID='saveAllElements' value='Done'  OnClick='saveMedia()'  Text='Done' />
```

**Javascript** - *code found on web*

```
function saveMedia() 
{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var data = new FormData();
    var files = $(".back").get(0).files;
    alert(files.length);

    if (files.length == 0) 
    {
        alert("No files");
    }
    else 
    {                  
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) 
        {
            data.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
        }     

        xhr.open("POST", "UploadHandler.ashx");
        xhr.send(data);                  
    }
};
```

Comment: why you are using `get` . Instead you can go for input values . It will also give you the whole path with file name .

Comment: ans what is the data.append doing . I mean where you have declared data variable ?

Comment: @TusharRaj can you give me an example, and FYI this div can be more than once on the same page (if it is matters..).

Comment: Data is declared at the second line for the function, the problem now is that files.length is always 1 no matter if i upload one file or more..

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie sorry maybe there was a problem with copy paste, I will recheck it now.